# Signing Virtualbox modules with EFI Secure Boot enabled

Tags: virtualbox, uefi, secure-boot

I have a system (22.04.1 LTS) with an Nvidia card and with EFI secure boot enabled.
Virtualbox refuses to run a VM and claims that

> if the system has EFI Secure Boot enabled you may also need to sign the kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetapd, vboxpci)

also

> VERR_VM_DRIVER not installed

How do I sign those modules?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, the issue isn't with *EFI*; it's with *Secure Boot*, which is just one specific UEFI feature. Secure Boot can be enabled or disabled and isn't even present on some (mostly older) EFI/UEFI implementations. I mention this because, if you can edit your question's title, doing so would be helpful to others.

Second, to answer your question, you must first have a Secure Boot Machine Owner Key (MOK) or Secure Boot db key installed in your computer. To do this, you must have both `openssl` and `mokutil` programs installed (from the `openssl` and `mokutil` packages, respectively). In brief:

1. Using a shell (Terminal program or text-mode login), create and change into a temporary directory.
2. Create a MOK. This is done by issuing two commands:

   ```
   openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout MOK.key -out MOK.crt -nodes -days 3650 -subj "/CN=Your Name/"
   openssl x509 -in MOK.crt -out MOK.cer -outform DER
   ```
3. Install this MOK in your computer's NVRAM. This can be done in various ways, but the easiest is likely to be to use `mokutil`. You begin by passing the `MOK.cer` file to `mokutil`:

   ```
   sudo mokutil -i MOK.cer
   ```
4. Note that `sudo` may ask for your account password; then `mokutil` will ask for a *new* password, and confirmation thereof.
5. Reboot the computer. If all goes well, you'll be asked to press a key to begin MOK management, then asked for a password -- enter the *new* one you gave `mokutil`. (In some recent experiments of mine, the system asked for specific random characters from the password, which is more awkward.) You can then confirm addition of your MOK to the NVRAM's MOK list. When you're done, reboot into Ubuntu.

With the MOK now stored in NVRAM, you can sign your VirtualBox driver binaries. In its most basic form, the command to do this is:

```
$path_to_binary/sign-file sha256 MOK.key MOK.cer $path_to_driver/vboxdrv.ko
```

Repeat this for `vboxnetadp.ko` and `vboxnetflt.ko`. The `sign-file` program is actually part of the Linux kernel source code; it's not a standard program in Ubuntu. You can find its location by typing `find /usr/src -iname sign-file`. If it's not installed, then you should install the `linux-headers` package. You can also use `find` to locate where the VirtualBox modules are, if you don't already know.

Once the modules are signed, you can load them with `modprobe` or reboot the computer.

I do this often enough that I wrote a script to automate the signing part of the process. This script will *not* automate the MOK creation, though. Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# sign-vbox script, copyright (c) 2017 by Rod Smith
# Distributed under the terms of the GPLv3

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ] && [ "$#" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 [ {kernel-version} ]"
    exit 1
fi

if [ "$#" == 0 ]; then
    kernel_version=$(uname -r)
#    apt-get install virtualbox-dkms --reinstall
else
    kernel_version="$1"
fi

sign_file=$(find /usr/src/ -name sign-file | tail -n 1)

if [ -z $sign_file ]; then
    echo "Can't find the sign-file binary! Exiting!"
    exit 1
else
    path_to_modules="/lib/modules/$kernel_version/updates/dkms"

    if [ ! -f $path_to_modules/vboxdrv.ko ]; then
        echo "Could not find $path_to_modules/vboxdrv.ko!"
        echo "Is the kernel version correct?"
        exit 1
    fi

    echo "Signing modules for $kernel_version"
    $sign_file sha256 /mnt/keys/MOK.key /mnt/keys/MOK.cer $path_to_modules/vboxdrv.ko
    $sign_file sha256 /mnt/keys/MOK.key /mnt/keys/MOK.cer $path_to_modules/vboxnetadp.ko
    $sign_file sha256 /mnt/keys/MOK.key /mnt/keys/MOK.cer $path_to_modules/vboxnetflt.ko
    modprobe vboxdrv
    modprobe vboxnetflt
    modprobe vboxpci
    modprobe vboxnetadp
    echo "Loaded vbox modules:"
    lsmod | grep vbox
fi
```

To use the script, first store it in a file and make it executable (`chmod a+x sign-vbox`, for instance, if that's the filename you use). You then execute the script as `root`, as in `sudo ./sign-vbox`. This will sign the *currently-booted* kernel's VirtualBox modules. (If you want to sign another kernel's modules, you can pass its version number as an option.) Also, the script uses a hard-coded location for the key files, which brings us to....

Be aware that the `MOK.key` file (or whatever you call it) is potentially quite sensitive. If an intruder gets ahold of that key, then the intruder could sign kernel modules or boot loaders and use it to get very low-level access to your computer. That's why this script accesses the key files in `/mnt/keys`; the idea is to put them on a removable disk and mount that disk only when it's needed. Store all of the keys generated earlier by `openssl` in this way. Adjust the script as necessary for wherever you store your keys.

Comment: as for finding virtualbox modules, [here](https://gist.github.com/reillysiemens/ac6bea1e6c7684d62f544bd79b2182a4) I found this suggestion

`for module in $(dirname $(modinfo -n vboxdrv))/*.ko; do
  log "Signing $(green ${module})..."
  sign-file "${hash_algo}" "${key}" "${x509}" "${module}"
done`

Comment: you can sign the kernel modules after rebooting by running 
``` sudo /sbin/vboxconfig  ```

Comment: "create and change into a temporary directory"
but it needs to survive rebooting process :D

Answer (score 5):

I just reinstalled the VirtualBox dkms package from terminal using:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms --reinstall
```

The installer prompted me to create the certificate, setup password for in MOK and gave clear instructions (to reboot and enroll the certificate in MOK).

Comment: I have the same issue with a Dell laptop for an end-user upon which I installed 22.04 LTS current and that does *NOT* allow legacy boot in the Dell BIOS.  "If all goes well," is stated before the Andrei B. answer, and I cannot afford end-user machine Ubuntu failure.   setup password for in MOK and gave clear instructions is stated by Andrei B. above.  Is MOK installed or must this be done?  Will sudo apt install ... work?  What else needs to be done?  Detailed instructions, please.

Comment: The mokutil package was installed already on my system by the Ubuntu installer, so I didn't have to install it myself. If you want to be on the safe side, you can do:
sudo apt install mokutil
before reinstalling the virtualbox-dkms packaged.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 23.10, virtualbox installer does not promt with MOK installation, virtualbox modules are zstd compressed, so additional signing steps needed

Based on:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/1456158/968164 (@rod-smith answer)
- https://gist.github.com/dublado/d0321da690c633e7799d5d504e3b52c1
- https://blog.unitedheroes.net/archives/p/5625/signing-kernel-modules-under-ubuntu-23-10/

```bash
# for illustration purpouses
cd

# install modules
apt-get install virtualbox-dkms --reinstall

# create certificate
openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout MOK.key -out MOK.crt -nodes -days 3650 -subj "/CN=Your Name/"
openssl x509 -in MOK.crt -out MOK.cer -outform DER

# move to dir with modules
cd $(dirname $(modinfo -n vboxdrv))

# they are compressed, you can't sign that
# decompress
# you might need to do this one by one, without wildcard
sudo zstd -d --rm vbox*

# sign modules (certs lies in $HOME, in this case)
# you might need to sign them one by one, without wildcard
sudo /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/scripts/sign-file sha256 ~/MOK.key ~/MOK.cer ./vbox*

# update modules info
sudo depmod

# install this MOK in your computer's NVRAM
sudo mokutil -i MOK.cer  # remember password

reboot

# press key to enter MOK management, add MOK,
#  type password you'v remembered previously
```